# Iterating over ArrayList and String at the same time to do replacement regex

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

I'm reading in an input HTML file with a load of tags in it like:

```
<h2 id="head-3d7e87e90500d3645e1f578a2b0fd6b4f7bd4ccf">
```

the `head-3d7e87e90500d3645e1f578a2b0fd6b4f7bd4ccf` is some random value.

I have all the necessary replacements in an ArrayList to make them look like, for example

```
<h2 id="correctAnchor">
```

But I loop through the `ArrayList` & over the HTML(parsed as a String) but it always replaces the last value:

```
    for (String temp2 : myAnchorLinks) {
        Pattern h2Pattern = Pattern.compile("<h2.*?>");
        Matcher h2Matcher = h2Pattern.matcher(replaceAllTags);
        if (h2Matcher.find()){
            replaceAllTags = replaceAllTags.replace("<h2 id=.*?>", "<h2 id="+temp2+">");        
        }

     }
```

any ideas what I'm doing wrong or is there a better approach?

"What is a wiki?
"

I can't post all the HTML but it looks like:

ArrayList = {#blah1, #blah2, #blah3};

Comment: Show us the bigger picture. What is `replaceAllTags`?

Comment: is it necessary to compile a new Pattern in every loop?

Comment: sure,
say my ArrayList is {#blah1, #blah2, #blah3}
`code`
replaceAllTags = replaceAllTags.replace("<h2 id=.*?>", "<h2 id="+temp2+">");
`code`
nothing changes
but with
`code` 
replaceAllTags = replaceAllTags.replaceAll("<h2 id=.*?>", "<h2 id="+temp2+">");
`code`
all <h2 id=#blah3>

Comment: @user1406476 Please edit your question with the additional code. Click the `edit` link at the bottom of your question to do so.

Comment: Edit your post and put the code in there, don't post it in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Matcher` you should use it instead of using `String` methods which create a new `Matcher`behind the scenes.

```
Pattern h2Pattern = Pattern.compile("<h2.*?>");
Matcher h2Matcher = h2Pattern.matcher("");
for (String temp2 : myAnchorLinks) {
    h2Pattern.reset(replaceAllTags);
    replaceAllTags = h2Matcher.replaceAll("<h2 id="+temp2+">");
}
```

Update: I guess, now I know what you are trying to do:

```
Pattern h2Pattern = Pattern.compile("<h2.*?>");
Matcher m=p.matcher(replaceAllTags);
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
for(Iterator<String> it=myAnchorLinks.iterator(); it.hasNext() && m.find(); ) {
  m.appendReplacement(sb, "<h2 id="+it.next()+">");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
replaceAllTags=sb.toString();
```

This will assign each occurrence of your pattern another `String` from your list. But you should care about what to do if the number of matches and elements in your list do not match. In my example it stops on whatever is smaller.

Comment: `reset` sets the input to search and resets the matcher’s state as well. But I guess, the second code is more what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map< String, String > replacements = new hashMap<>();
fillReplacements( replacements ); // Create associations between old and new IDs
// maybe from a properties file
for( map.Entry< String, String > e : replacements.entries()) {
   htmlSource = htmlSource.replaceAll( e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first and most critical error is using `replace()` instead of `replaceFirst()`.

`replace()` replaces *plain text* (not regex)
`replaceAll()` and `replaceFirst()` use regex to find the match to replace

Try this:

```
replaceAllTags = replaceAllTags.replaceFirst("<h2 id=.*?>", "<h2 id="+temp2+">");
```

Comment: still the same result I'm afraid.

Comment: better add example input (both html and array) and expected output. btw your regex atm chews up the quotes

Comment: IF you use replaceFirst with the regex used in a loop always is replaced the fist item and not all others

Comment: @Dubas you're right. unless the regex doesn't rematch already replaced targets. I think the match regex isn't going to work properly. The question is pretty flimsy anyway, so I'm not inclined to spend a lot if time on it.

Answer (score 0):

Regex matches always as much as possible. So, if you have a String like

```
<hello world="this"/> is such a nice <place/>
```

and you match this with the regex `<hello world=.?>`´it will return the whole String as it ends with a ">" - not just the first part of it as you might have expected.

Your regex should be `<h2 id=[^>]*>` then the match stops at the ">".

If you want to test your regular expressions, here is a [good regex tester](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) that gives you also how to escape the regex in Java.

Comment: No the question uses reluctant quantifiers, e.g. `.*?`

Comment: @Holger. Cool, I learned something today. I just tried `<h2 id=.*>` and `<h2 id=.*?>` and understand now the difference. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to do something like this:

```
// Original String
String HTML="aslasasd <h2 id=\"head-abcdefg\">   <h2 id=\"head-hij5345345345n\">";

// Ids to replace secuentially
String[] ids ={"#id1","#id2"};

// Replace pattern
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<h2[^<>\"']id=\"([^\"]*)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(HTML);
int i = 0;

// Loop for each id that match and replace the ramdom id with the next
// id in the list.
while(matcher.find()){
    HTML = HTML.replace(matcher.group(1),ids[i]); // replace Id
    i++;
    if (i > ids.length){
        break; // No more ids to replace
    }
}

// Replaced String
System.out.println(HTML);
```